# h:outputLabel not showing anything

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

The problem that I am facing is that after I click on the `h:commandLink` button the `h:outputLabel` isn't showing anything. I have used selectedUser to store the value when the form is submitted but it seems selectedUser is not storing any value.

1)Here is the xhtml file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">


<h:head></h:head>



<h:body class="thrColElsHdr">


        <div class="friends">

        <h4>Friends</h4>
        <h:form>
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{chatBean.selectedUser}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{chatBean.friendList}" var="users" itemLabel="#{users.firstName}" itemValue="#{users}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <h:commandLink>Chat</h:commandLink>
        </h:form>
        <br>
        </br>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{chatBean.selectedUser.firstName}"/>


        </div>




</h:body>
</html>
```

2)Here is the chatBean and it is session scoped using facesconfig.xml

```
package com.bean;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.entity.Friend;
import com.entity.User;

public class ChatBean {
    private EntityManager em;
    private User selectedUser;


    public User getSelectedUser() {
        return selectedUser;
    }


    public void setSelectedUser(User selectedUser) {
        this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
    }


    public ChatBean(){
        selectedUser= new User();
        EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("FreeBird");
         em =emf.createEntityManager();
    }


public List<User> getFriendList(){

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        User user=(User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Friend f WHERE f.email='"+user.getEmail()+"' AND f.status=1",Friend.class);
         List<Friend> results =query.getResultList();
         ArrayList<User> friends = new ArrayList<User>();
         Iterator<Friend> it = results.iterator();
          while(it.hasNext()){
              System.out.println("in getFriendList...");

             User friend =em.find(User.class,it.next().getFriendEmail());
             friends.add(friend);
         }
          return friends;
}
}
```

3) Here is the user entity class

```
package com.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the user database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String email;

    @Lob()
    private String aboutMe;

    private String birthDate;

    private String city;

    private String college;

    private String confirmation;

    private String contactNo;

    private String country;

    private String degree;

    private String firstName;

    private String gender;

    private String highSchool;

    private String image;

    private String interest;

    private String lastName;

    private String password;

    private int pincode;

    @Lob()
    private String quote;

    private String relationship;

    private String secondarySchool;

    private String state;

    private String street;

    private String university;

    private String userName;

    public User() {
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAboutMe() {
        return this.aboutMe;
    }

    public void setAboutMe(String aboutMe) {
        this.aboutMe = aboutMe;
    }

    public String getBirthDate() {
        return this.birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(String birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCollege() {
        return this.college;
    }

    public void setCollege(String college) {
        this.college = college;
    }

    public String getConfirmation() {
        return this.confirmation;
    }

    public void setConfirmation(String confirmation) {
        this.confirmation = confirmation;
    }

    public String getContactNo() {
        return this.contactNo;
    }

    public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getDegree() {
        return this.degree;
    }

    public void setDegree(String degree) {
        this.degree = degree;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return this.gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getHighSchool() {
        return this.highSchool;
    }

    public void setHighSchool(String highSchool) {
        this.highSchool = highSchool;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getInterest() {
        return this.interest;
    }

    public void setInterest(String interest) {
        this.interest = interest;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getPincode() {
        return this.pincode;
    }

    public void setPincode(int pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

    public String getQuote() {
        return this.quote;
    }

    public void setQuote(String quote) {
        this.quote = quote;
    }

    public String getRelationship() {
        return this.relationship;
    }

    public void setRelationship(String relationship) {
        this.relationship = relationship;
    }

    public String getSecondarySchool() {
        return this.secondarySchool;
    }

    public void setSecondarySchool(String secondarySchool) {
        this.secondarySchool = secondarySchool;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return this.state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return this.street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getUniversity() {
        return this.university;
    }

    public void setUniversity(String university) {
        this.university = university;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `<h:commandLink>` is missing the method expression. Also, your mananged doesn't have method to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: You mean the action or actionListener property? Actually I don't want to fire any method when the link is clicked, I only want to display the value of the selectedUser.firstName by using the outputLabel. I suppose the value of selectedUser is instantiated when I submit the form.

Comment: @BheshGurung you can update the value without having a defined action.  Still, you would need to update the control in some way. You should refresh the whole page or update the controls by an ajax render.

Comment: Why are you using `<h:outputLabel>` instead of `<h:outputText>`? Are you aware that `<h:outputLabel>` renders a HTML `<label>` element? In the context as in your code it seems to be completely misplaced. A HTML `<label>` is intented to label a HTML `<input>` element. If you want to show plain text, just use `<h:outputText>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your managed bean must have the corresponding annotations:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class ChatBean {
    //...
}
```

The example can be corrected using one of these tips:

- Add an `action` to your `<h:commandLink>` and bind it to a method that returns the name of your page. In this way, the page will be refreshed and it will show the new value in `#{chatBean.selectedUser.firstName}`:

  ```html
  <h:commandLink action="#{chatBean.refresh}" value="Chat" />
  ```

In your class:

```
public String refresh() {
    return "index";
}
```

- Add ajax behavior to your `<h:commandLink>` in order to update the `<h:outputLabel>`. You should add an id attribute to your `<h:outputLabel>`:

  ```html
  <h:commandLink value="Chat">
      <f:ajax render=":theLabel" />
  </h:commandLink>
  <!-- jsf code -->
  <h:outputLabel id="theLabel" value="#{chatBean.selectedUser.firstName}"/>
  ```

Comment: Do I need to set any navigation rule for the "index" outcome?

Comment: What about `h:selectOneMenu` and `f:selectItems` with `User`? Doesn't he need a converter for that?

Comment: That was in the old days of JSF 1.x. Since JSF 2.0, you just need to return the name of the view where you want to navigate, the framework will look for the view (note: there's no need to add the `xhtml` at the end of the returned `String`).

Comment: @BheshGurung yes, but that's outside of the main question.

Comment: @Bhesh: perhaps the OP already has a `@FacesConverter(forClass=User.class)`. In any way, a conversion error should otherwise have made that clear enough (but so far, the OP doesn't seem to indicate that he has got any conversion/validation error messages in the server logs or the view).